# :hover select stops working after I reset a element's z-index in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a `<div>` called `.right-search` I have written the following `:hover` selector for it to change the background of the `<div>`:

```
.right-search:hover{
  background:#eab63e; 
}
```

This same element is the target of a `.click()` even in jQuery. The click handler, displays some hidden material that is initially set to `display:none` changes the z-index of `right-search` during that time. And then I reset to the initial `z-index` of 100.

What is *bizarr* is that before the event is fired, the `hover` effect works perfectly. And after, even after all of the data has been set to its initial value, it doesn't work, the same.

If you try clicking the "EN" on the right of the top nav you will see what I mean, after you click it once more:

https://jsfiddle.net/k8zxkntt/6/

Answer (score 2):

You are setting the CSS Background to an inline colour, which will override the CSS.  Make your `else` remove the background colour instead:

```
else{
  // Set the background to '' instead of a forced colour:
  $('.right-search').css('background','');
  first_trans_click = true;
  $('.right-search').css('z-index','100');
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/k8zxkntt/7/